# Why isn't a module being read by my View-backed Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller calls the method `bar`:

```
class CompsController < ApplicationController
   include ApplicationHelper

   def quick_create
      @var = Matview.bar @projects
   end
end
```

bar is defined in a model that represents a materialized view in my database (it is not in my schema):

```
class MatView < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

  table_name = 'mat_views'

  def self.bar(arg)
    foo arg
  end

end
```

'bar' calls method `foo`, which is defined in my ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def foo(arg1)
       #do stuff
   end
end
```

I've included the ApplicationHelper in both my controller and model, and yet I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in CompsController#quick_create
undefined method `foo' for Matview(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

why?

Comment: if it extends `ActiveRecord::Base`, it's not a table-less model, sorry.

Comment: thanks.  i've corrected my headline.

Comment: Why is the materialized view not in your `schema.rb` or `structure.sql`?

Comment: I thought you're not supposed to include materialized views in the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matview.bar @projects
```

Is calling a *class* level method on the `MatView` class.

But your `foo` and `bar` are both *instance* method definitions. To make them class methods, you need `def self.bar(arg)` or `def self.foo(arg1)`

And to get class methods into your ActiveRecord model, you need to `extend`, not `include` the module:

```
class MatView < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ApplicationHelper
end
```

Or, if that does not sound like what you meant to do, then maybe you meant to do:

```
Matview.new.bar @projects
```

in which case the instance methods like you wrote them should work.

Comment: Thanks, the 'self' was a typo which I fixed. I tried the extend and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you fix `self.foo` as well? In the question, the `foo` method is still an instance method...

Comment: but foo is an instance method that sits in ApplicationHelper and gets extended throughout rails via `include`.

Comment: If `foo` has to remain an instance method, then you must call it from within an instance method. So `bar` has to be an instance method, and `quick_create` has to be: `@var = Matview.new.bar @projects`

Comment: ahhh....so I read this [article](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) and now I understand what you're saying.  The answer as you pointed out is to use `extend` rather than `include`.  Thank you!